# Define OSGi DS Reference Filter with multiple properties

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix

My question is simple, is it possible to create a @Reference filter based on more than a single property? If so, what is the syntax?

For background, my service looks like this:

```
@Component (property = {"myProp1=foo", "myProp2=bar"})
public class MyService implements IMyService
...
```

The thing that uses IMyService only wants one where myProp1=foo and myProp2=bar. I have tried various syntax forms and have not found one that works yet.

```
private @Reference (target = "(myProp1=foo)(myProp2=bar)") IMyService svc;
```

The above actually does resolve and I get a reference, however an error is logged, "Invalid syntax in target property for dependency...". So even though it works, it appears to be a fluke because there is some issue with the syntax.

```
private @Reference (target = "((myProp1=foo)(myProp2=bar))") IMyService svc;
private @Reference (target = "((myProp1=foo) (myProp2=bar))") IMyService svc;
private @Reference (target = "((myProp1=foo), (myProp2=bar))") IMyService svc;
private @Reference (target = "{(myProp1=foo), (myProp2=bar)}") IMyService svc;
private @Reference (target = "[(myProp1=foo), (myProp2=bar)]") IMyService svc;
```

None of the above even compile which is nice to have validation.

```
private @Reference (target = "([myProp1=foo, myProp2=bar])") IMyService svc;
private @Reference (target = "(myProp1=foo, myProp2=bar)") IMyService svc;
```

That above compile but simply don't return a service.

```
private @Reference (target = "(myProp1=foo)") IMyService svc;
```

Filtering on a single field as shown above works just fine but it is not the complete solution I am looking for.

The [javadoc for the @Reference annotation](http://javadox.com/org.osgi/osgi.cmpn/6.0.0/org/osgi/service/component/annotations/Reference.html#target()) does not provide any guidance on how to use the "target" parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can, the filter format is 'ldap style'. The and operator is the '&', and you use it before your sub expressions.

In your case it would be something like:

`(&(myProp1=foo)(myProp2=bar))`

For reference:
https://osgi.org/javadoc/r2/org/osgi/framework/Filter.html

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks for the doc link. I had not found that on my own.

Comment: That link is really REALLY old... it's for OSGi Release 2 which was around 1999! Fortunately the documentation for that specific method is still good, but for other things please refer to the latest release documentation at https://www.osgi.org/osgi-release-6-javadoc/

Comment: If using xml rather than annotations remember to write the & as &amp;